# What are the differences between the Proxmark3 and the Chameleon Mini?

Tags: rfid, nfc

I want to play with RFID/NFC cards and I need a tool to read, write and emulate tags. I know the **Proxmark 3** (http://www.proxmark.org/), but I also heard about the new **Chameleon Mini** (https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/1980078555/chameleonmini-a-versatile-nfc-card-emulator-and-mo) already available for order.

- Talking about features, which one should I use for studying RFID/NFC cards?
- Do the Proxmark support UHF? Does it matter?
- Are they equally easy to use? The proxmark has been around for a long time so I guess there is more documentation available.

Thanks for your help!